# Django-Tailwind not working properly in Django

Tags: django, tailwind-css

Django-Tailwind initially after setup works well with Django, but as soon as I start progressing with my project, it stops working!!!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a terminal with the comand:
python manage.py tailwind start
?

Dont close this terminal.

Comment: Please ask your questions as comments, not asnwers.

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this issue and I figured it out. Open a separate terminal window and run:

```
python manage.py tailwind start
```

then in a separate terminal window run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Keep both of these terminals open and running and your tailwind should recompile and display on save.

One more tip, in your tailwind.config you'll see a section in the purge object with this comment:

> /*  Templates within theme app (<tailwind_app_name>/templates), e.g. base.html. */

It will be helpful to add to this to capture html documents elsewhere in your project so instead of just the first line, I added this:

```
    '../../**/*.html',
```

It will probably help your tailwind compiling to not cast quite as wide a net looking for html files but it isn't bogging down my compiling too much.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Not working properly" is a little vague -- though sometimes I still put that in a message board or slack :-)

In case you've run into this page and you created a new template and all of a sudden it seems to have "stopped working" ... check your template has this at the top:

`{% load static tailwind_tags %}`

and in the head:

`{% tailwind_css %}`

See: https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html